# Sequelize Querying with Op.or and Op.ne with same array of numbers

Tags: sql, sequelize.js

I'm having trouble getting the correct query with sequelize.
I have an array representing ids of entries lets say its like this -

```
userVacationsIds = [1,2,3]
```

i made the first query like this

```
        Vacation.findAll({
          where: {
            id: {
              [Op.or]: userVacationsIds
            }
          }
        })
        .then(vacationSpec => {

          Vacation.findAll({
               where:{
               //Here i need to get all entries that DONT have the ids from the array
             }
            }
          })
```

I can't get the correct query as specified in my code "comment"

I've tried referring to sequelize documentation but i can't understand how to chain these queries specifically

Also tried an online converter but that failed too.

Specified the code i have above

So i just need some help getting this query correct please.
I eventually expect to get 2 arrays - one containing all entries with the ids from the array, the other containing everything else (as in id is NOT in the array)

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

I feel silly.

This is the query that worked

```
        Vacation.findAll({
          where: {
            id: {
              [Op.or]: userVacationsIds
            }
          }
        }).then(vacationSpec => {


          Vacation.findAll({
            where: { 
              id: {
                [Op.notIn]: userVacationsIds
              }
             }
          })
```